# Magento installation not working after editing php.ini

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I tried to install Magento 2.4.5 on windows I am using windows 8.1 by the way and I downloaded xampp8.1.12, composer 2.4.4, and when I typed this command

`composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition`

I got this error :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.5-p1].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 requires ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
  Problem 2
    - magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.7.0, ..., 3.12.0] require ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
    - Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^3.7 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.7.0, ..., 3.12.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files PHP uses in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-intl` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

The strange thing is that I removed the comma from all of these extensions in the php.ini file:

extension=gd

extension=intl

extension=soap

extension=sockets

extension=sodium

extension=xsl

and I still have the same error

and by the way, when I restart xampp I get this error:

`The Procedure entry point crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar _ reduce could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\xampp8.1\php\ext\php_sodium.dll`

I tried running this command

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure below all extensions are enabled in php.ini

```
sodium
ext-bcmath
ext-ctype
ext-curl
ext-dom
ext-gd
ext-hash
ext-iconv
ext-intl
ext-mbstring
ext-openssl
ext-pdo_mysql
ext-simplexml
ext-soap
ext-xsl
ext-zip
ext-sockets
```